# Firebase Realtime Database security concern

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I'm using the Firebase Realtime Database in an Android app.

There are some nodes in the database that have to be accessible even to anonymous users. I have made the security rules as secure as possible, however, I'm wondering if there are any other ways to increase the level of security.

For example, what if someone uses my `google-services.json` file on his app? Will he be able to create new anonymous users in my database? If he reverse engineers my app, then possibly he will manage to find the nodes that an anonymous user has read/write access and he will be able to modify that data.

So, how do we prevent this type of scenario? Is there a way to secure the database to allow connections only from my SHA-1 signing-certificate fingerprint? I've found that in the Google APIs console (https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials) you can restrict the Android client to your own SHA-1 certificate and package name, however I am not sure if that works with Firebase. Is that safe enough or can someone "fake" the SHA-1 certificate?

Comment: Hi Steliosf,

Did you find any solutions. I am facing same problem please help me to solve my issue Thank you

Comment: Hi @ShafqatKamal I think if you restrict the Android client to your own SHA-1 certificate and package name using the link I provided, it should be secure. Although I'm not 100% sure. You probably need to add the SHA-1 both of the signing certificate and the debug keystore, otherwise you won't be able to access the database in your development environment.

Comment: HI @Steliosf Thanks again for your reply. Yes i understand what do you mean. But for your kind information i have done same thing. After that i change my app package name and i used different keystore file to generate signed and debug apk but i used same information of my project like web apk key database path but still i am able to access database :(. Please help me to solve my issue. Thanks

Comment: @ShafqatKamal When I was working on that, I remember that I couldn't access the database with a different package name after doing that configuration. Maybe you didn't modify the correct key. Instead of the Android client shouldn't you do that in the Web client or something? I don't think I can help since I no longer work on that project, but if you contact Firebase support they will most likely be able to help you.